# List USB Devices Like \\?\Device\HarddiskX\PartitionY VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Is there any way to get list of connected USB devices in "\?\Device\HarddiskX\PartitionY" Format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at : [How Can I Determine Which USB Devices are Connected to a Computer ?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/15/how-can-i-determine-which-usb-devices-are-connected-to-a-computer.aspx)

Comment: Thank you I got it, I can use wmiDiskPartition.DeviceID to get Disk X and Partition Y of every Device.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers, because they'll become useless if the referenced source disappears. Quote the relevant content in addition to the link.